# Name of induced map

Tags: linear-algebra, convention

If we have three $k-$vector spaces $V,W,U$, then, for a linear map $T:V\to W$ we have an induced map $T^*:L(W,U)\to L(V,U)$ defined by $T^*(f)=fT$. This map is usually called the transpose of $T$.

But we also have another induced map $T_*:L(U,V)\to L(U,W)$ defined by $T_*(f)=Tf$. Does this one have a particular name?

Comment: The transpose of a linear map $T\colon V\to W$ is defined as the map $T^*\colon W^*\to V^*, \phi\mapsto \phi\circ T$. (Intuitively it should be clear that it shouldn't depend on some arbitrary third $k$-vector space $U$ )

Comment: @Hyperplane Note that $W^* = L(W,k)$.  This definition is not something I'm used to, but it generalizes the usual notion of a transpose so that the target space need not be one-dimensional.

Comment: The map $T_*:L(k,V) \to L(k,W)$ define by $T_*(f) = T \circ f$ could be called the "multiplication map", perhaps. We canonically identify it with $T$ by identifying $v$ and the map $\alpha \mapsto \alpha v$ from $k$ to $V$.